# Conditionally delete a node in neo4j from kafka connect handling debezium data from a postgresql DB

Tags: apache-kafka, neo4j, debezium

I'm trying to implement a postgresql -> Debezium Kafka Connect source -> Kafka -> Neo4j Kafka Connect sink -> Neo4j. The data sent by debezium contains events which contain a field `op = "c/u/d"` (create/update/delete). The example docs show a pattern using `FOREACH` to test if the create/update should happen and that part works. What I couldn't get to work is how to delete a node if a `op = "d"` event comes in (I see it in the topic).

My current cypher line for that kafka topic looks like this (formatted, the original is one long line):

```
FOREACH (run_me_once in CASE WHEN event.op <> 'd' THEN [1] ELSE [] END | 
  MERGE (p:DemoTable{id: event.after.id}) 
  SET p.message = event.after.message, p.last_changed = event.ts_ms
) 
WITH event
MATCH (p:DemoTable{id: event.after.id}) 
FOREACH (run_me_once in CASE WHEN event.op = 'd' THEN [1] ELSE [] END | 
  DELETE p
)
```

This doesn't show any error, but it also doesn't delete any nodes.

I tried multiple versions of the delete part until I arrived at this:

- Without `WITH event` (Error about `MATCH` and `FOREACH` only works with `WITH`),
- With running match in the foreach (no `MATCH` in `FOREACH` allowed),
- Using `DELETE (p:DemoTable{id: event.after.id})` within the `FOREACH` (error about `expected whitespace or a relationship pattern` at the end of the code)

What is the right pattern to conditionally handle delete events?

Comment: Which example docs show the FOREACH pattern? I can find no such examples in neo4j

Comment: I think it was https://neo4j.com/docs/kafka/kafka-connect/sink/ but it seems it got updated since then and the pattern is now much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: the [tutorial](https://neo4j.com/docs/kafka/kafka-connect/sink/) now describes a CDC to Neo4j pattern which seems to be much easier than the below (haven't tried).

OLD ANSWER:

Found the problem: the event from debezium for a delete has `event.after = null` and so in the delete, it needs `MATCH (p:DemoTable{id: event.before.id})`.

Final code:

```
FOREACH (run_me_once in CASE WHEN event.op <> 'd' THEN [1] ELSE [] END | 
  MERGE (p:DemoTable{id: event.after.id}) 
  SET p.message = event.after.message, p.last_changed = event.ts_ms
) 
WITH event
MATCH (p:DemoTable{id: event.before.id}) 
FOREACH (run_me_once in CASE WHEN event.op = 'd' THEN [1] ELSE [] END | 
  DELETE p
)
```